# Container With Gutters

Tags: html, css, containers, margin

I'm trying to create a page with 20px gutters on the top, bottom, left, and right of the page. The current setup for my container doesn't seem to work for the 20px gutter I want to have on the ride side of my container

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="neo_wrapper">   <!-- Wrapper start -->
    <div class="neo_container"> <!-- Container start -->
        <div class="neo_header-fixed"></div>
        <div class="neo_column_a"></div>
        <div class="neo_column_b"></div>
        <div class="neo_column_c"></div>
        <div class="neo_footer-fixed"></div>
    </div>  <!-- Container end -->
</div>  <!-- Wrapper end -->
</body>
```

And my CSS

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}


/* Wrapper for entire page */
.neo_wrapper{
   width: 100%;
   height: 900px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Container for content */
.neo_container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 120px -20px 50px 20px;
 }

/* Fixed header */
.neo_header-fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #999;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.neo_column_a{
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #063;
    float: left;
}

.neo_column_b{
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #00F;
    float: left;
}

.neo_column_c{
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #F00;
    float: left;
}

/* Fixed footer */
.neo_footer-fixed{
    position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   background: #999;
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

And jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x0cfdm5r/

Comment: I guess gutter is padding or margin :)

Comment: Consider ordering your markup differently. Put your fixed header and footer outside of the wrapper. That way you can have only the three content columns inside the wrapper, apply the margin (not gutter) to the wrapper, and voila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `margin` from `.neo_container` and apply `padding` to `.neo_wrapper`

Also you should use the CSS property `box-sizing`, check more info on that [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)
and [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0)

Look [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/international-box-sizing-awareness-day/) why you should (not mandatory) use `box-sizing`

> *With the default box-sizing, as soon as an element has either padding or border applied, the actual rendered width is wider than the width you set...*
>
> *You might think of it this way: with box-sizing: border-box the padding and border press their way inside the box rather than expand the box. The result is a box the exact width you set it to be and can count on.*

Take a look at the below snippet:

```css
/* CSS Document */

/* This is our reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
/* Wrapper for entire page */

.neo_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 120px 20px 50px 20px;
}
/* Container for content */

.neo_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*background: #000;*/
}
/* Fixed header */

.neo_header-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.neo_column_a {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #063;
  float: left;
}
.neo_column_b {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00F;
  float: left;
}
.neo_column_c {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #F00;
  float: left;
}
/* Fixed footer */

.neo_footer-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="neo_wrapper">
    <!-- Wrapper start -->
    <div class="neo_container">
      <!-- Container start -->
      <div class="neo_header-fixed"></div>
      <div class="neo_column_a"></div>
      <div class="neo_column_b"></div>
      <div class="neo_column_c"></div>
      <div class="neo_footer-fixed"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Container end -->
  </div>
  <!-- End of wrapper -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding instead of margin for your gutters, then you can use `box-sizing` (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x0cfdm5r/5/

```
/* Container for content */
.neo_container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 120px 20px 50px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*background: #000;*/
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as negative padding!

Comment: Oh sorry my fault, forgot about that. I fixed it in my answer, thanks :)

Comment: just remember that you are forgetting the browsers vendors on the box-sizing property, which won't make it cross browser :)

Comment: yes that's true, you explained it better in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/x0cfdm5r/2/

```
/* Wrapper for entire page */
.neo_wrapper{   
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 120px 20px 50px 20px;
}


/* Container for content */
.neo_container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `position: relative` on the wrapper - it makes it easier to work with paddings the way you'd like to.

Change these:

```
/* Wrapper for entire page */
.neo_wrapper{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Container for content */
 .neo_container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 100px 0 30px 0;
}
```